# Confusing behavior when pattern matching on Options

Tags: rust

Could somebody explain why the below code prints `Matched`? The variables `first_vec` and `sec_vec` have totally different values.

```
fn main() {
    let the_vec = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let first_vec = the_vec.get(0);
    let sec_vec = the_vec.get(1);
    println!("The first_vec is: {:?}", first_vec);
    println!("The second_vec is: {:?}", sec_vec);

    if let Some(first_vec) = sec_vec {
        println!("Matched");
    } else {
        println!("Unmatched");
    }
}
```

The program prints

```
The first_vec is: Some(1)
The second_vec is: Some(2)
Matched
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if let Some(val) = option` always matches if `option` is `Some` and never if `option` is
`None`. Since `sec_vec` is `Some(2)`, the pattern will always match. If you are trying to compare `first_vec` and `sec_vec`, you can just do `if first_vec == sec_vec`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it gave an unexpected result is because you were using an assignment.

```rust
if let Some(first_vec) = sec_vec {
    println!("Matched");
} else {
    println!("Unmatched");
}
```

The `if let x = y` expression you had is equivalent to this match.

```rust
match sec_vec {
    Some(first_vec) => println!("Matched"),
    None => println!("Unmatched"),
}
```

The purpose of the if let is to get a variable if the match is true. So in your case, it is trying to match the `Some(_)` and if successful create a variable `first_vec` with its contents. The `if let x = y` is meant to be used in cases where you only need a single case so having the full match is somewhat redundant.

```rust
let the_vec = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
let first_vec = the_vec.get(0);
let sec_vec = the_vec.get(1);

// Instead you could match both to be some with a tuple
if let (Some(first), Some(sec)) = (first_vec, second_vec) {
    // Then check if they are the same value (you can't merge if let statements)
    if first == sec {
        println!("Matched");
    }
}

// Or you could use an if in your match, but I personally find this syntax less
// verbose and usually don't inline the if even when I can.
match (first_vec, sec_vec) {
    (Some(first), Some(sec)) if first == sec => println!("Matched"),
    _ => println!("Unmatched"),
}
```

Comment: Hello Locke, the above didn't work for me, below Psidoms comment makes sense. it still said matched.

Comment: Thanks Locke for the explanation

Comment: I added an explanation on how the match could be made work, but @Psidom is right that `first_vec == sec_vec` would be the most correct solution for your use case.